# Is it OK to have a method's variable with the same name as a declared property?

Tags: objective-c, variables, properties

I understand this is probably bad practice, but I was just curious as to whether or not this **has any negative side-effects**, in Objective-C (trying to learn as much as I can):

```
@interface MyClass ()

// Declare a string called 'foo'

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *foo

@end

@implementation MyClass 

...

- (void)modifyFoo {

    // Create a local variable with the same name as a property

    NSString *foo = @"Hello!" // No compiler warnings?

    self.foo = foo; // <---- Is this OK?

}
```

This will not throw up a warning in the compiler, and sure enough, my code works as normal. *If* there are zero negative side-effects, does the type of property, e.g. weak/strong/assign, etc, have an influence on whether or not this is OK?

*Note: I am aware that this will not work when the property is synthesised.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fine and is my personally preferred approach. The reason no compiler warning is generated is that the instance variable is actually named `_foo`. This is done by the auto-synthesise added by the compiler (it generates `@synthesize foo = _foo` for you). Maintaining naming consistency aids clarity.

The main potential side effect is that you inadvertently add / fail to add `self.` and end up trying to message `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly:

> this will not work when the property is synthesised.

Huh? Why not?

---

Actually, it's "OK" in the sense that it works. Actually, there's no ambiguity when you use the `self` keyword and the dot notation to access your property. If, however, you had an **instance variable** with the same name as your local variable, then the object with a narrower scope (the local variable in this case) hides the one with a wider scope (the ivar). And that may be undesirable. As far as I know, it even results in a compiler warning. Furthermore, it's hard to get it wrong and decreases overall code readability, so don't do this if you have that identically named instance variable.

If I recall correctly, recent versions of the clang/LLVM toolchain automatically synthesize properties for you, and the name of the backing ivar for a property is preceded by a leading underscore, so this should not be a problem.

Comment: Some people would just do `@synthesize foo` to synthesize and then you'd start to get issues with name duplication.

Comment: @Wain "so don't do this if you have that identically named instance variable."

Comment: I was alluding to what @Wain mentioned, as that's what I used to do before the compiler automatically synthesised a '_'. Thanks for the insight, H2CO3 :)